# How to implement Javascript Leaflet demo code to show a simple map and point? (blank page returned)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I try to just imitate the simplest example code of Leaflet (https://leafletjs.com/index.html) as follows. But somehow I only got the blank page. Can somebody spot what is wrong? Many thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Map view with Leaflet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>    
</head>

<body>    
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
        L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(map);
        L.marker([51.505, -0.09]).addTo(map);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at your browser's error console. What do you see?

Answer (score 2):

Height of this `<div id="map"></div>` is 0px so it is collapsed, set some height, 100% of fixed.
E. g.:

```
<style>
    #map {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

Actually, it was just missing `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beggining of the code.
Silly, but this solves the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Map view with Leaflet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>    
</head>

<body>    
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
        L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(map);
        L.marker([51.505, -0.09]).addTo(map);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well doctype wont help here, I've tested in chrome, height is still 0